# Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) for a Code in CodeChef

Tags: c++, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

I'm a beginner and this is my first problem on Code Chef.
I run my code on my machine and it works fine, but after I submit it on Code chef I get this error Runtime Error(SIGSEGV). 
Am I using too much memory for the problem or am I giving the input wrong?

Here my code ,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#include <math.h>
#define D(a,b) fabs(a-b)
#define Q(x1,y1) (sqrt((x1)*(x1)+(y1)*(y1)))
#define min(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    long int i,k,testno,cones;
    double N[1000],dmid,r,R,x1,y1,temp=0;

    cin >> testno;
    for(i=0;i<testno;i++){
        cin >> r >> R;
        dmid=D(r,R)/2;
        cin >> cones;
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            cin >> x1 >> y1;
            if(Q(x1,y1)>dmid){
                N[k]= R-Q(x1,y1);
            }
            else{
                N[k]=Q(x1,y1)-r;
            }
        }    
        for(k=0;k<cones-1;k++){
            temp=min(N[k],N[k+1]);
        }
        printf("%.3f",temp);
        cout << endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

And the link to the question : http://www.codechef.com/problems/COURSE
EDIT: Cant believe I made such a ridiculous mistake. Anyways, I've edited the code but still getting the same error.

Comment: You are not scanning the values of r and R!

Comment: What did you find out when debugging your code? Uninitialized variable values?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I was getting that initially for the array N, but after assigning it a size, I didnt get that error.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote...

```
for(k=0;k<3;k++)
```

considering that, there will always be **3** cones. But it's wrong. You took **cones** as input. So this line must be,

```
for(k=0;k<cones;k++)
```

Through this edition you will get rid of **Runtime Error**. But to be fair, your current solution is far away from the correct solution. You can read the editorial of this problem from [this link](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/4248/course-editorial) to get the right idea. Best of luck. :)